# How to extract values inside an XML tag-python 3

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree, xml.etree

Nelow is a sample XML file that i want to parse through and get the value between the year tags(2008)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

Is there any way to extract the data between the year tags (2008.2011,etc) and print it using python?

Here is the code so far:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for year in root.iter('year'):
   print(year.attrib)
```

But when i try that code, nothing prints. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: try print (year.text)

Comment: could i message you to help me real quick please

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple to do it using lxml:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse("country_data.xml")
tree.xpath('//year/text()')
```

Output:

> ['2008', '2011', '2011']

Comment: can i message you real quick

Answer (score 1):

You can use BeatifulSoup for this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

years = []

with open('country_data.xml') as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'lxml')

    for country in soup.findAll('country'):
        years_data = country.find('year')
        years.append(years_data.contents[0])

print('Years: {}'.format(years))
```

Output:

```
Years: ['2008', '2011', '2011']
```